# What to do, when I was hacked

Tags: security

Over the past week this Superfish crap has appeared all over my Magento website it's literally hijacked it.

What should i do?

Comment: Dear Alex, although I'm not too familiar with this thing called "Superfish crap" after some Googling it seems it's spyware. Did you encounter this on just your computer or also others. I would recommend you contact your hosting provider if it really is on your shop or search out a developer that can help you by going through your shops code

Comment: Its called "Super Fish" and yeah it's on the actual website i've tested from several different computers / phone, even had friends test it for me. Usually It's malware that installs it's self on someone's computer, but somehow its actually on my site! I don't get it when i go to other websites either. It's really weird... I hope someone can help, ive been looking for answers all day on google.

Answer (score 6):

What to do, when you was hacked:

1. Disconnect the server from the internet
2. Find the security issue, the hacker/malware came into your machine
3. Fix the bug
4. Get a new server
5. Install a backup, including the bugfix
6. put that machine back online
7. make a image from the old machine, give it to the police

NEVER NEVER put the old machine back on the net. It is not trustable anymore, no one have a clue what happend on the machine and if there is more.

Comment: Especially if it's a shared server. The host itself is probably compromised which means every host account is compromised. Change service providers.

Comment: Changing the host is enough, but this is not easy profable.